# Retrieve Package Name & Package Version of the Installed Packages in Org

Tags: package

Is it possible to retrieve Package Name & Package Version of the Installed Packages in your Org programmatically?

Comment: The suggested duplicate is similar, but different enough that I can't justify marking as duplicate.

Comment: `sfdx force:package:installed:list -u prod`

Answer (score 0):

Using the tooling API (version 34.0 and later), you can retrieve the information of installed packages with the following SOQL. See [Publisher](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_publisher.htm) documentation for other field references you may be interested in.

```
List<Publisher> packages = [
                select Name,
                  MajorVersion,
                  MinorVersion
                from Publisher];
```

Comment: The SOQL on Publisher does not give the name of the installed package. It gives the name of the publisher for the installed package. Do you have any other suggestions?Thanks